# How to load Fragment using AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to load fragment after alert Dialog  response but when i attempt to load logcat shows "IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to Activity". Generally IllegalStateException comes when you try to perform work after the Fragment is no longer attached to the Activity. but in my case every thing is fine i don't understand why fragment is not attached to an activity.

this is my MainActivity:

using this class i call DilogCreate which extends DialogFragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                new DilogCreate(view.getContext(),R.string.tilte,R.string.no,R.string.yes);
            }
        });
    }
```

this is my DilogCreate class:

on the basis of dialog response decide fragment can be loaded or not if dialog response yes i call another activity name Second.java under this class i try to load fragment.

```
    public class DilogCreate extends DialogFragment {
        AlertDialog alertDialog;


        public DilogCreate(final Context context, int tilte, int no, int yes) {

            AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDilog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            mAlertDilog.setNegativeButton(yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, second.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            alertDialog = mAlertDilog.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    }
```

this is my my Second.java class:

this class is appear because of dialog response and under this class i tried to load fragment.

```
public class Second extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loadFragment);

        fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        Myfragment myfragment=new Myfragment();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.cont,myfragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

this is MyFragment.java extends Fragment :

```
public class Myfragment extends Fragment{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag,container,false);
    }
}
```

Logcat status:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment DilogCreate{8aea1d4} not attached to Activity
```

please help me guys i have no idea why this error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

```
new DilogCreate(view.getContext(),R.string.tilte,R.string.no,R.string.yes);
```

pass **MainActivity.this** instead of **view.getContext()**.You need to pass activity context here.

Comment: view.getContext() is a activity context so both are same

Comment: There is no guarantee that the Context used by your view is an Activity, and I think you would want to pass Activity reference here for passing to the builder.

Comment: He got it. Also, why are you passing Strings to an int parameter?

Comment: @klutch R.string.xyz is a string resource id, all resource ids in android are int. To get a string from it, you need to call context.getString(R.string.xyz)

Comment: @codemonger thanks for ans.. but this is not the solution of my problem see my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

fragment is load on the activity and one activity switch to another by using base reference that's why i need to call startActivity() method using base Activity refrence.

so i change startActivit() method in the DilogCreate class like this:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context,Second.class);
context.startActivity(intent);//make sure context is the refrence of the base context
```